# CakePHP: "GET" form does not auto-populate form fields after submission

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, query-string, cakephp-2.3

I'm using Cake 2.3.0. If I submit my form using `POST`, the selected form fields carry over however if I submit my form using `GET`, all of the form fields return to their default values.

Is there a way to make the `GET` submission to work like that of the `POST`?

Here's my contorller:

```
class ListingsController extends AppController {
    public function results() {
        $conditions = array(
            'Listing.Beds >=' => $this->request->query['beds'], 
            'Listing.ListingStatus >=' => $this->request->query['status'], 
        );

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
        );    

        $this->set('listings', $this->paginate());
    }
}
```

Here's what my view looks like.

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'controller' => 'listings', 
    'action' => 'results',
    'type' => 'get'
));

echo $this->Form->input('name');

$beds = array('1' => '1+', '2' => '2+', '3' => '3+', '4' => '4+', '5' => '5+');
echo $this->Form->input('beds', array('options' => $beds));

$status = array('Active' => 'Active', 'Pending' => 'Pending', 'ActivePending' => 'Active and Pending');
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('options' => $status));

echo $this->Form->end('Update');
```

So basically if I change `'type' => 'get'` to `'type' => 'post'` it works just fine. But I need to be able to do this via `GET`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this is annoying (IMO CakePHP should be smart enough to automatically determin 'where' to get its data from, based on the 'type').

You'll have to copy the 'query' of the request to the 'data' of the request;

```
$this->request->data = $this->request->query;
```

Not behind my computer to test it (as usual, lol), but should probably work.

Comment: I actually had already tried this and it didn't work. What I Was able to do was loop through the $this->request->query array and pass those values to the matching $this->request->data. But as was pointed out to me in a chat room, that is the "the hard and spagetti way" and probably shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: Apparently (see the answer of @ADmad below), the 'official' way is to use PRG, personally, this doesn't 'feel' right though, IMO 'searching' should not use 'POST'? You can of course create a customised formHelper that will automatically get the data from request->query if the form-type is 'get'. If implemented correctly that doesn't sound very 'spaghetti' to me.

Comment: I agree, search feels like it should be using `GET` and I don't think I should have to use a plugin or component to do something that seems like it should be out of the box. This was much simpler with CodeIgniter.

Comment: Implement it the way *you* think fits your purpose best. Try to implement it in a 'decent' way to prevent spaghetti. I'm interested to hear from other people though where my 'error' is in thinking that a 'search' form should simply use 'get' :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your controller:

```
$this->request->data = $this->params['url'];
```

Comment: I tried adding that in  couple of places to the controller and that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$this->params->data = array('Tablefilter' => $this->params->query);
```

where "Tablefilter" depends on form definition (usually the model name)

```
$this->Form->create('Tablefilter', array('type' => 'get'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Checkout [this](https://github.com/CakeDC/search) plugin.

Comment: Doesn't PRG only apply to situations where data is 'posted'? I've always wondered why 'get' forms in CakePHP aren't automatically propagated with the corresponding query-data. The search-plugin may be a good suggestion though in this case.

Comment: Yes it does and I am suggesting to POST the form. Pre-filling form based on GET data is not common practice. But if want you can easily make a component to do so.

Also cake specific annoyance when using GET to submit forms is your field names would be of form data[Foo][bar] generally. Having those in URL would be ugly.

Comment: +1 on the 'ugly' formatting of those fields (I normally override the names for searching). Still not convinced on 'POST' for search-forms as I think 'POST' (and 'PUT') should be reserved for *modifying* data, but that may be a matter of opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was looping through the `$this->request->query` array and pass those values to the matching `$this->request->data`.

So I added this:

```
foreach($this->request->query as $k => $v){
    $this->request->data['Listing'][$k] = $this->request->query[$k];
}
```

Which ultimately gave me this:

```
class ListingsController extends AppController {
    public function results() {

        foreach($this->request->query as $k => $v){
            $this->request->data['Listing'][$k] = $this->request->query[$k];
        }

        $conditions = array(
            'Listing.Beds >=' => $this->request->query['beds'], 
            'Listing.ListingStatus >=' => $this->request->query['status'], 
        );

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
        );    

        $this->set('listings', $this->paginate());
    }
}
```

I'm not going to accept this as the answer though as I don't know if this is the optimal or suggested way to do it. But it works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

$this->request->data['Cluster'] = $this->params->query ; //controller side

Form definition:

$this->Form->create('Cluster',array('type'=>'get'));